# Adding custom operations to Admin console in jboss 7.1.1

Tags: jboss7.x

I want to expose custom operations using jboss console. Like in jboss 4.2, we were using xmbeans to create our own interface & then invoke operations.
I found sample (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Example+subsystem) related to creating custom subsystem but that can be accessed using CLI only.However If its possible to expose the same set of operations and attributes in the web (admin) console?
If not, is there any plan for it?

Thanks for your help.

Best Regards,
Divya Garg